# Does anyone know any good tool to convert CLSID and ProgID?

Tags: c#, clsidfromprogid

I'm trying to find out if there is any handy tool that can convert between CLSID and ProgID ( mostly from CLSID to ProgID).

also, im not sure which area i should categorize my post into, if i post wrong place, please help me edit it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regedit.exe works well.  Navigate to `HKCR\xxxx` where xxxx is the ProgId to find the CLSID.  Navigate to `HKCR\CLSID\{xxxx}` where xxxx is the CLSID to find the ProgId.  Some COM servers don't register their ProgId in the CLSID key, simply search for the CLSID to find it.

The only other wrinkle is 64-bit operating systems, keys for 32-bit COM servers are stored in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes.

Comment: And some COM objects don't have a ProgId. It's not required.

Answer (score 0):

I could only find some [legacy VB code that calls OLE](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18927) - might be helpfull in giving you the right direction for .NET